# Scroll View only scrolls after zoom, came up when I fixed autolayout (constraints)

Tags: swift, scrollview

I've made a ScrollView with a imageView in it... Evrything worked fine... after making constraints the Scroll View is only scrolling when I've zoomed in or out...
Does anyone know a solution?

thx!

Comment: did you try to set scrollView.contentSize

Comment: I fix it by making a constraint to the bottom to 0. thank you for your help!